# Creating custom shortcut in Texstudio

Tags: texstudio, shorthands

For some reason, keyboard's quotation mark (`"`) does not work properly in `Texstudio`. Since i am using `csquote` package i would like to create a custom shortcut for the command `\textquote`.

However, i don't know how to do it in `Texstudio`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeXstudio can automatically convert "real" quotation marks to \enquote{}.
Take a look at the Editor tab in the settings.

Comment: Note though that this doesn't work with .Rnw files. So a hotkey would still be useful to some.